Getting 'null' error while pulling data from the database in C# & ASP.NET web
First of all, I have 13 image buttons on a page and I defined their ids like image_1, image_2, image_3....
In my database, I hold image IDs and images like in photo.
All image buttons are empty in Visual Studio designer rn.
Here's my code:
protected void PlaceImages()
{
    string query = "SELECT imageID, image FROM images WHERE imageID BETWEEN 1 AND 13";

    using (MySqlConnection connection = ConnectDB())
    {
        connection.Open();

        using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection))
        {
            using (MySqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    int imageID = Convert.ToInt32(dr["imageID"]);
                    byte[] imgData = (byte[])dr["image"];
                    string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imgData, 0, imgData.Length);

                    string controlID = "image_" + imageID;

                    ImageButton imgButton = (ImageButton)FindControl(controlID);

                    imgButton.ImageUrl = "data:image/png;base64," + base64String;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

I get this error:

imgButton was null.

on this line of code:
imgButton.ImageUrl = "data:image/png;base64," + base64String;

How can I solve this problem?
I tried to use this code
imgButton.ImageUrl = "data:image/png;base64," + base64String;

in an if statement to check if its not null. But this time, nothing changed in my image buttons.

I'm guessing FindControl is failing - you'll have to figure out why that is

I have defined the image button ids correctly, why might I be getting an error?

please share your webform code

you should also consider a repeater control instead.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater?view=netframework-4.8.1

<asp:ImageButton ID="image_1" runat="server" Height="410px" Width="600px" />
here's one of them.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/hw8sf6fb(v=vs.100)

Have you confirmed this line is returning an image ID? int imageID = Convert.ToInt32(dr["imageID"]);

Yeah i did, it does. @nardnob

This won't give you an ImageUrl, but to avoid the null-reference exception you can do (note the question mark): imgButton?.ImageUrl = "data:image/png;base64," + base64String;

What does string controlID give?

image_1, image_2, image_3....... @sr28

What does the html actually show the control id as? Do you have a master page or something like that?

The page I'm working on is a Web Form with Master Page.

This looks like a similar problem to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11145980/get-id-of-master-page-object-in-content-page

Nvm, I used switch(imageID) instead of FindControl. Thank you guys for help!
